# Filter Calculated Model

Tags: google-app-maker

I am trying to use a **calculated model** in Google App Maker to store data from an external API. I am able to load the data to a model and render it in a table. But now I want to filter the data in the table without calling the external API again.

For example if I use the Weather (Call REST services) sample code, after the weather is rendered on screen I want to click a button to only show the days with the temperature is below 32F. How would I do that without calling the external APIs again to reload the model.

Answer (score 0):

After talking out loud, I believe I can answered my own question. I hope this helps others and please correct me if I am wrong.

What I am asking isn't possible with Calculated Models. How a Calculated Model works is the server script (query script) calls the external database, receives the data and formats (cleans up) the data following a Datasource. The datasource cleans up the data to fit within the Model before returning the data as Records to the 
Client. Once the data is on the Client everything on the serve is forgotten.

So to search the data 2 options I can think of:

1. Create different Datasources, Models or Parameters that calls the external database every time and returning the filtered data to the Client.
2. Or use the javascript filter() method on the records already loaded to client and some extra code and ui to show the filtered results. The filter() method doesn't modify the records on the client but the results can shown on another table.